# "Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField Class" with Pivot Table Filtering Attempt

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot, current-page

So I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong for the past two days and I can't seem to get past this error.

The error is "Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField Class"

Here is my code:

```
Sub FilterBasedOnCellValue()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim PFilter As String
 Dim pf As PivotField
 Dim filterValue As String
 Dim leftp As String
 Dim rightp As String

 Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Activity Report (Automated WIP).xlsm")
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Formulas")
 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DailyActivity")
 Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Activity_RAW].[Column1].[Column1]")
 Set rng = ws.Range("Filter")

 leftp = "&["
 rightp = "]"
 PFilter = "[Activity_RAW].[Column1]." & leftp & rng & "T00:00:00" & rightp

  With pf
   .ClearAllFilters
   .CurrentPage = PFilter
   .RefreshTable
  End With


End Sub
```

The Line that seems to cause it is the ".CurrentPage = PFilter" line.

The "Column1" filter is in the actual "Filter" field for the pivot table. and when I record a macro of filtering it, it uses CurrentPage, which is why I am confused.

My Pivot Table is an OLAP Based Pivot so I am not certain if I am using the right code for it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Found out what was causing the issue!

I needed to change ".CurrentPage" to ".CurrentPageName"

I will post it here for anyone that might be running into the same issue that I was!

```
Sub FilterBasedOnCellValue()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim PFilter As String
 Dim pf As PivotField
 Dim filterValue As String
 Dim leftp As String
 Dim rightp As String

 Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Activity Report (Automated WIP).xlsm")
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Formulas")
 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DailyActivity")
 Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Activity_RAW].[Column1].[Column1]")
 Set rng = ws.Range("Filter")

 leftp = "&["
 rightp = "]"
 PFilter = "[Activity_RAW].[Column1]." & leftp & rng & "T00:00:00" & rightp

  With pf
   .ClearAllFilters
   .CurrentPageName = PFilter
  End With
 
  pt.RefreshTable

End Sub
```