# Filter a pivot table based on a cell value (OLAP)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, olap-cube

I'm trying to create a filter in a pivot table based on a cell value in Excel VBA. I have found this code below but it does not work.
I have attached a screenshot containing the pivot table. I want to filter "M?nad" as "May" (which is the input in cell D69).

```
Sub FilterPageValue()
Dim pvFld As PivotField
Dim strFilter As String
Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("M?nad")
strFilter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("220").Range("D69").Value
pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter
End Sub
```

While doing this i reach a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.
Name of pivot table are "PivotTable7".
Name of sheet are "220".
Input value is in cell D69.
Note that the data comes from a external source (OLAP Cube) which I think is the main reason of this issue.

Please help! :-)

[image: Pivot Table]

I tried debug with:

```
Sub abc() Debug.Print 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields(2).Name 
End Sub
```

Then I get: [Dim_Kalender].[Månad].[Månad]

Therefore i tried following code:

```
Sub FilterPageValue() 
Dim pvFld As PivotField 
Dim strFilter As String
Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields(" 
[Dim_Kalender].[Månad].[Månad]") 
strFilter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("220").Range("D69").Value 
pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter 
End Sub
```

Now I am stuck on     "pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter". Same error as before.

Comment: Always helps to mention on which line the error occurs

Comment: It seems like it is this row:
Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Månad")

Comment: Try looping over the fields and `Debug.Print` each of the field names, to see if they're different from what you expect.

Comment: I have updated my code with trying to understand this.

Comment: What kind of value is in `strFilter` ?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean here but it’s a text. “May” formatted as text

Comment: Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72135184/unable-to-set-the-currentpage-property-of-the-pivotfield-class-with-pivot-tabl   Are you getting the exact same error message as before?

Comment: Now I have tried and I can see that it is the same part. It's bugging by "pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter"/ " .CurrentPageName = PFilter"

Comment: Try looping over `pvFld.Items` and check their names are what you expect.  Sorry I don't have access to an OLAP table to check anything out.